# Mistaken "Paper jam inside" error message on Brother 5470DW printer

Tags: printer

My Brother HL5470DW printer keeps showing a "Printer Jam Inside" error message, even though there was no jam. I have done all the things that are suggested. I even cleared it once by unplugging the cord for a few minutes and starting it up again, but now nothing works. I wondered whether replacing the printer in the "Print and Fax" system preferences on my MacBook Pro laptop might help. I've updated the printer driver but couldn't do that with the hardware because of the phoney printer jam. Is there anything else I can do? I spoke to some people who claimed to know the Brother model (Brother won't help me, because the printer is out of warranty). They didn't seem to know anything about the printer and told me just to get a new one.

I really like the printer, so if there's anything you can think of to do that I haven't done, please tell me. (I've cleaned it, taken out the toner repeatedly, opened every door and compartment I can, and removed the cable from both ends.)  I'll be so grateful.

Comment: Have you checked the sensors?

Comment: A dust ball or tiny piece of paper can fool a sensor. The path has to be _clean_.

Comment: Remove everything you can from the printer, and check everywhere for little pieces of paper.

Comment: Thank you. I have been over the printer for just such things, repeatedly. I don't really know where the sensors are, though. I did notice that a corner of one of the (very stiff) plastic sheets that lie on the rubber rollers is very, very slightly turned up. I don't know whether that would fool the printer into thinking it had a piece of paper, dust or anything else stuck in the printer, but there seems to be no way to bend it gently back into place. I thought of heating it slightly but am concerned about trying that without knowing what I'm doing.

Comment: And now, somehow I deleted the printer from my Printers preference in the the Mac system preferences. Because of the error message, I can't add it back! That error keeps everything from moving ahead.

Comment: Has anyone any idea whether the little bend on the plastic item that partly covers one of the rollers in the front may have caused the printer to mistake it for a paper jam. And if so, is there anything I can do about it? Thanks so much.

Comment: And where are the sensors? Should I Google this, or can you tell me?

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue with my DCP-7070DW. Symptoms was exactly same as described by user 'hehemule' here: https://www.reddit.com/r/printers/comments/epfjco/troubleshoot_brother_hl2280dw_laser_printer_jam/ .
I used my printer occasionally, total printed pages from date of buy was about 450. I tried all recommended actions, but nothing of it helped me to solve problem. Every print was ending in 'jam inside' message, and print was stoped every time at same place. Nothing helped:  cleaning, disassembling and re-soldering connectors, resetting ... After many hours I found this:   https://www.fixya.com/support/t13453542-fix_paper_jam_in_brother_mfc_7860dw (see anotony's answer). After turning printer on while holding 'start' button printer started working without any issues. Turning printer on without 'start' button pressed caused issue returned. It seems, that it is something wrong with initialization, firmware or some non-volatile settings. Today I updated firmware in printer (from manufacturer site) and it seems, that issue is gone. Maybe it helps someone.

Update: Firmware update does not helped, issue persist. Only turning printer on with 'start' button pressed helps.

Comment: In the same way, factory resetting will clear any temporary NVRAM values, and is probably easier to do than finding a firmware upgrade (if one is even available) for the printer.